# What happens to the argument of a trigonometric function when multiplied by a constant?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, arithmetic

so I was training my derivation skills when I stumbled upon deriving trigonometric functions,, and during one step of the chain rule I wit the following:

$$ -35\cos(-15x) \cdot (-15) = 525\cos(15x)$$

and at this point I am confused, why does the sign of the argument of $\cos$ change all of a sudden? :( why would it affect its argument too?

thank you very much in advance for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $525$ simply comes from $(-35)(-15)$ (two negatives multiply to give a positive).

The argument changes sign because $\cos (-x) = \cos x$. You can justify this in a number of ways, the easiest being to look at the signs of the trigonometric ratios in the four quadrants. Cosine is positive in the first and fourth quadrant, and the fourth quadrant can be thought of as angles in the range $[-\frac{\pi}2,0)$ (the "mirror" of positive acute angles). Another way is to look at the graph of the cosine function and observe that it's an even function. Still another way is to study the behaviour of the Maclaurin series for cosine. And so on.

Comment: oh alright! so basically $cos(-kx) = cos(kx)$ and $sin(-kx) = -sin(kx)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Linshao Exactly.

Comment: alright!! 谢谢你 :))

Comment: @Linshao 不客气 :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos y$ is an [even function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions), $\cos(-15x)=\cos(15x)$ is an optional sign change for the argument.